# Replace values in a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset

```
 Longitude Latitude Radius Site_Type 
      <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     
1    -102.      1.5       5 OBS       
2     -80.0    27.1       5 OBS       
3    -158.     21.5       1 FEE;OBS   
4     -81.6     3.98      1 FEE;OBS;NA
5     -87.0     5.50      1 OBS       
6     -90.7    -0.55      1 FEE;OBS   
7    -110.     24.7       1 FEE;OBS;NA
8     -89.5    28.4       1 OBS       
9     -91.8     1.38      1 FEE;OBS
```

I want to replace NA by OBS I tried using replace() but nothing changed...

Comment: In base R you can use `df$Site_Type <- gsub('NA', 'OBS', df$Site_Type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NA` is character here so `str_replace` replace might work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Site_Type = str_replace(Site_Type, "NA", "OBS"))
#   Longitude Latitude Radius   Site_Type
# 1    -102.0     1.50      5         OBS
# 2     -80.0    27.10      5         OBS
# 3    -158.0    21.50      1     FEE;OBS
# 4     -81.6     3.98      1 FEE;OBS;OBS
# 5     -87.0     5.50      1         OBS
# 6     -90.7    -0.55      1     FEE;OBS
# 7    -110.0    24.70      1 FEE;OBS;OBS
# 8     -89.5    28.40      1         OBS
# 9     -91.8     1.38      1     FEE;OBS
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` in `base R`

```
df1$Site_Type <- sub("NA", "OBS", df1$Site_Type)
```